# Any clue why these elements are being drawn in another view?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

This strange behaviour happens when I have another window over my main window and perform a command that opens a modal popup in the main window. The outline of the selector and the Approved button are drawn in the modal window like the images show:

[image]

Where I think the elements are coming from:

[image]

However, if the window becomes out of focus and in focus again, the elements disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems I solved it. I don't know exactly why it was happening, but it probably had something to do with the multiple calls I was doing to `- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect;` in order to modify the selector border when hovering the mouse. Now I call my custom method, `- (void)showBorder;` which does only: `self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;`.